# How to prevent sprite from doing 360 flip in cocos2d

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, sprite

So basically i have a turret and i rotate it to face the tapped position on the screen using

```
[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:duration angle:angle];
```

It works 90% of the time but then sometimes the sprite that i am rotating will out of nowhere do a 360 flip, I have no idea why and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: CCRotateTo calculates the angle difference for you and chooses shortest distance to rotate, but my question is why isnt it rotating?, its flipping the sprite which is odd to me, ill post code though if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out it was a bug with the cocos2d rotateto class,
this link helped correct it
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/56028